Recognizing Euler products
Is there a standard approach in Mathematica for recognizing Euler products? For example, I have the following product
$$\prod_{p} \frac{1-p^{s}+p^{2s}}{\left(p^s-1\right)^2}.$$
There is a nice closed formula for this, which is $\zeta(s)\zeta(2s)\zeta(3s)/\zeta(6s)$, and we can easily verify the result once we know what it is. However, having only the product over the primes above, we would need to factor that expression in a very particular way to get the result. Namely,
$$\frac{1-p^{s}+p^{2s}}{\left(p^s-1\right)^2} = \frac{1-p^{-6s}}{(1-p^{-s})(1-p^{-2s})(1-p^{-3s})}.$$
This is all most likely far-fetched, but is there a function in Mathematica that gives various factorizations of an expression, or perhaps something that can recognize values and guess a function that generates those values? (I tried FindSequenceFunction[], but no success). More realistically, I just want to be able to extract some information about these types of products so I can make better guesses.

Are you looking for products that only yield products of powers of zeta’s?

@GregHurst Euler products that yield products of values of zeta would already be sufficient for me. If there are more general methods, I'd also be interested to know about.

By change of varible $q=p^s$, your expression becomes $f(q)= (1-q+q^2)/(q-1)^2$. All zeros and poles of $f(q)$ are located on a unit circle in the complex $q$ plane --- actually they are all roots of 1. So $f(q)$ must be a product of the polynomials (or its reciprocal) of the form $(q^{k_i}-1)^{m_{i}}$. You can easily guess what they are.

If you have more complicated example, please put it in MMA readable code. Then we can try making it as a Euler-Product form.

@A.Kato I posted a list of expressions that you can test your code on. I am not sure about their difficulty.

@azerbajdzan Thank you very much! That was very useful to debug my code.

This answer is based on my comment to the original question.
Essentially you are asking a method to rewrite the given expression as
a ratio of products of forms $1-p^{-ks}$, where $k$ is a positive integer.
By change of variable $q=p^{-s}$, your expression becomes a rational
function $f(q)$ of $q$, and wanted result is an expression of $f(q)$ as
a ratio of products of forms $1-q^k$.
It is now clear that this is possible only if zeros and poles of $f(q)$ are all roots of unity. Since there are only finite number of zeros and poles, there is a positive integer $n$, such that they are all $n$-th root of unity.
Let $d$ be a divisor of $n$. Then the root of $1-q^{n/d}=0$ appears every $d$-th point on the set of $n$-th root of unity. So, a factor $(1-q^{n/d})^m$ would contribute zero (resp. pole) of multiplicity $m$ (resp. $-m$).
Let $\{d_{1}, d_{2},\cdots, d_{r}\}$ be the set of all divisors of $n$.
Paying attention to the order of zeros and poles at the $n$-th root of unities,
the problem of finding $m_{i}$'s such that $f(q)=\prod_{i=1}^{r} (1-q^{n/d_{i}})^{m_{i}}$ becomes a linear-algebra problem for the unknowns $m_{1},m_{2},\cdots,m_{r}$.
Here is a sample input data. The first one is your original, and the rest are suppled by azerbajdzan.
Clear["Global`*"]

test = {(1 - p^s + p^(2 s))/(p^s - 1)^2, 
   1 - p^(-9 s) + 3 p^(-6 s) - 3 p^(-3 s), 
   p^(-6 s) (-1 + p^(2 s)) (1 + p^s + p^(2 s))^2, (p^s + 
      p^(3 s))/(-1 + p^(3 s)), (1 + p^s + p^(2 s))/(-1 + p^s)^2, (1 + 
      p^(2 s))/(1 + p^s + p^(2 s)), 
   1 + 1/(-p^s + p^(2 s)), (p^(7 s) (1 + p^s + p^(2 s)))/(1 + 
      p^(4 s) (-1 - p^s + p^(5 s))), 
   p^(7 s)/(-1 - p^s + p^(6 s) + p^(7 s)), (1 + p^s + p^(2 s))/(-1 + 
      p^s + p^(3 s)), 
   1 - p^(-5 s) + p^(-2 s) - 
    p^-s + (-1 + p^s)/(1 + p^(2 s)), (1 - p^(-6 s) - p^(-5 s) - 
      p^(-4 s) - p^(-3 s) + p^-s + p^s + p^(2 s))/(1 + p^s + p^(2 s)),
    1/(1 + p^(-2 s) + p^-s), (-1 + p^s + p^(4 s))/(-1 + 
      p^(2 s)), (-1 - p^s - p^(2 s) - p^(3 s) + p^(6 s) + p^(7 s) + 
      p^(8 s) + p^(9 s))/(p^(5 s) + p^(6 s) + p^(7 s) + p^(8 s) + 
      p^(9 s))};

Now change the variable:
qtest = Factor[PowerExpand[test /. p -> Exp[-1/s*Log[q]]]]


Here is the main program which realizes the task explained above:
ClearAll[mkprod, q];
mkprod[f_] := 
  Module[{zeros, poles, rot, n, div, bb, aa, ans},
   zeros = SolveValues[Numerator[f] == 0, q];
   poles = SolveValues[Denominator[f] == 0, q];
   If[Not@AllTrue[Union[zeros, poles], RootOfUnityQ],
    Return["N.A."]];
   rot[z_] := Block[{x}, x = Arg[z]/(2 Pi); x - Floor[x]];
   n = LCM @@ (Denominator[rot[#]] & /@ Union[zeros, poles]);
   div = 
    Sort[Tally[
       Join[{rot[#], 1} & /@ zeros, {rot[#], -1} & /@ poles]] /. {{x_,
          sgn_Integer}, m_Integer} :> {n*x, sgn*m}];
   bb = Total[UnitVector[n, #[[1]] + 1]*#[[2]] & /@ div];
   aa = Table[
     Boole[Mod[i, k] == 0], {i, 0, n - 1}, {k, Divisors[n]}];
   ans = 
    Inner[Power, (1 - q^(n/#)) & /@ Divisors[n], LinearSolve[aa, bb], 
     Times]
   ];

Grid[{#, mkprod[#]} & /@ qtest, Frame -> All]


Note that those entries with "N.A." have a zero or pole at $q=0$, which is not a root of unity.
The final code (including change of variables) will look like:
ClearAll[euler, p, s];
euler[f_] := 
  mkprod[PowerExpand[f /. p -> Exp[-1/s*Log[q]]]] /. q -> p^(-s);

Grid[{#, euler[#]} & /@ test, Frame -> All]



+1. A good work.

That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much.

Excellent. Is it possible to have an expression that after substitution has only roots of unity but still cannot be expressed as Euler product or every expression with only unity roots can be expressed this way?

@azerbajdzan I'm not an expert in number theory so I don't know what is the precise condition. But at least, it is necessary that the (multi-)set of zero and poles must be invariant under Galois group action.

If the tricky transformation of the product term is done by hand, Mathematica 14.1 on Windows finds it.
Product[(1 - Prime[n]^(-6 s))/((-Prime[n]^-s + 1)*(1 - Prime[n]^(-2 s))*(1 - 
Prime[n]^(-3 s))), {n, Infinity}]


(Zeta[s] Zeta[2 s] Zeta[3 s])/Zeta[6 s]


This is not an answer just a list ep of expressions someone can test their code on to find Euler product.
All but a few can be expressed as a product.
ep = {1 - p^(-9 s) + 3 p^(-6 s) - 3 p^(-3 s), 
 p^(-6 s) (-1 + p^(2 s)) (1 + p^s + p^(2 s))^2, (
 p^s + p^(3 s))/(-1 + p^(3 s)), (1 + p^s + p^(2 s))/(-1 + p^s)^2, (
 1 + p^(2 s))/(1 + p^s + p^(2 s)), 1 + 1/(-p^s + p^(2 s)), (
 p^(7 s) (1 + p^s + p^(2 s)))/(1 + p^(4 s) (-1 - p^s + p^(5 s))), p^(
 7 s)/(-1 - p^s + p^(6 s) + p^(7 s)), (
 1 + p^s + p^(2 s))/(-1 + p^s + p^(3 s)), 
 1 - p^(-5 s) + p^(-2 s) - p^-s + (-1 + p^s)/(1 + p^(2 s)), (
 1 - p^(-6 s) - p^(-5 s) - p^(-4 s) - p^(-3 s) + p^-s + p^s + p^(
  2 s))/(1 + p^s + p^(2 s)), 1/(
 1 + p^(-2 s) + p^-s), (-1 + p^s + p^(4 s))/(-1 + p^(2 s)), (-1 - p^
  s - p^(2 s) - p^(3 s) + p^(6 s) + p^(7 s) + p^(8 s) + p^(9 s))/(
 p^(5 s) + p^(6 s) + p^(7 s) + p^(8 s) + p^(9 s))}

$$\begin{array}{l}
 -p^{-9 s}+3 p^{-6 s}-3 p^{-3 s}+1 \\
 p^{-6 s} \left(p^{2 s}-1\right) \left(p^{2 s}+p^s+1\right)^2 \\
 \frac{p^{3 s}+p^s}{p^{3 s}-1} \\
 \frac{p^{2 s}+p^s+1}{\left(p^s-1\right)^2} \\
 \frac{p^{2 s}+1}{p^{2 s}+p^s+1} \\
 \frac{1}{p^{2 s}-p^s}+1 \\
 \frac{p^{7 s} \left(p^{2 s}+p^s+1\right)}{\left(p^{5
   s}-p^s-1\right) p^{4 s}+1} \\
 \frac{p^{7 s}}{p^{6 s}+p^{7 s}-p^s-1} \\
 \frac{p^{2 s}+p^s+1}{p^{3 s}+p^s-1} \\
 -p^{-5 s}+p^{-2 s}-p^{-s}+\frac{p^s-1}{p^{2 s}+1}+1 \\
 \frac{-p^{-6 s}-p^{-5 s}-p^{-4 s}-p^{-3 s}+p^{-s}+p^{2
   s}+p^s+1}{p^{2 s}+p^s+1} \\
 \frac{1}{p^{-2 s}+p^{-s}+1} \\
 \frac{p^{4 s}+p^s-1}{p^{2 s}-1} \\
 \frac{-p^{2 s}-p^{3 s}+p^{6 s}+p^{7 s}+p^{8 s}+p^{9
   s}-p^s-1}{p^{5 s}+p^{6 s}+p^{7 s}+p^{8 s}+p^{9 s}} \\
\end{array}$$

This is nothing but the comment to your comment to the question. 1 - p^(-9 s) + 3 p^(-6 s) - 3 p^(-3 s) == Expand[(1 - p^(-3 s))^3] outputs True. Hope the rest is clear to you.

@user64494 Yes, I tried to make a list of different difficulty so there should be very simple ones and hopefully also more tricky ones.

@user64494 And also the point of OP's question is to make it by code not by guessing the correct result or by brute force.

This is not an answer, but a suggestion for extension (too big as a comment).
Take for example the OEIS sequence A065764, sigma(n^2), multiplicative with a(p^e) = (p^(2*e+1)-1)/(p-1)
From there it gets the expression
 1 + Sum[(p^(2*e+1)-1)/(p-1) / p^(e*s), {e, 1, Infinity}]
 (* (p^s (p + p^s))/((-1 + p^s) (-p^2 + p^s)) *)

Expressing a similar Dirichlet generating function using the Zeta function(s) is very useful for further analysis.
Unfortunately, the euler function mentioned in previous answer gives the result N.A., even though the expression using Zeta functions exists:
 zeta[s_] := 1/(1 - 1/p^s);
 zeta[s]*zeta[s-1]*zeta[s-2]/zeta[2*s-2] // FullSimplify

 (* (p^s (p + p^s))/((-1 + p^s) (-p^2 + p^s)) *)


I noticed this too. That function ended up being sufficient for me since it solved most of my problems, but it does have some issues. As you pointed out, it returns N.A. for some cases where a factorization exists. My guess is that it fails to recognize equivalent forms.

All of these computations should be automatic. The issues seems to be a failure to reduce products to canonical forms. For example,
Product[(1 - 1/Prime[n]^s)^3, {n, 1, Infinity}]

works, but
Product[-(1/Prime[n]^s - 1)^3, {n, 1, Infinity}]

fails, even though these are obviously identical products.

Does the latter infinite product converge?
